# How many 7 digit sequences can be formed using the digits 1 and 2

Tags: combinatorics

How many 7 digit sequences can be formed using the digits 1 and 2 if two 1's cannot be consecutive?

Example: 1121222 is not allowed but 1221212 is allowed.

Comment: One idea if you don't want to involve a general counting technique with recurrence : consider there are two "characters" : 2, and 12, and separate the words ending with a 1... Several cases to work out.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam what means correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726915/find-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-n-digit-binary-sequences-with-no/1728216#1728216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_k$ denote the number of sequences of length $k$ that do not contain two consecutive $1$'s.  Then $a_1 = 2$ since both the sequences $1$ and $2$ are permissible and $a_2 = 3$ since the sequences $12$, $21$, and $22$ are permissible while the sequence $11$ is not permitted.

Let $k \geq 3$.  Since a permissible sequence cannot contain consecutive $1$'s, for a sequence of length $k$ to end in a $1$, it must be preceded by a $2$.  Thus, a permissible sequence of length $k$ that ends in $1$ can only be formed by appending the sequence $21$ to the end of a permissible sequence of length $k - 2$, of which there are $a_{k - 2}$.  A permissible sequence of length $k$ that ends in a $2$ can be formed by appending a $2$ to the end of a permissible sequence of length $k - 1$, of which there are $a_{k - 1}$.  Hence, the number of permissible sequences of length $k$ is given by the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
a_1 & = 2\\
a_2 & = 3\\
a_k & = a_{k - 1} + a_{k - 1} & \text{if}~k \geq 3
\end{align*}
You can use the recurrence relation to determine $a_7$.

Comment: \begin{align*} a_1 & = 2\\ a_2 & = 3\\ a_k & = a_{k - 1} + a_{k - 2} & \text{if}~k \geq 3 \end{align*}

Comment: @DnShVr  Thanks for correcting the error.

Answer (score 1):

When no 1s are used, there is $1$ possibility

When one 1 is used there are $7$ possibilities

When two 1s are used there are $\binom 62=15$ possibilities

When three 1s are used there are $\binom 53=10$ possibilities

When four 1s are used there is just $1$ possibility.

Therefore the total is $34$